# Why doesn't RabbitMQ support AMQP over HTTP instead of STOMP?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, stomp

I understand that HTTP is text-based and AMQP is binary-based, but why can't AMQP be implemented over HTTP (meaning every binary message was sent as an HTTP payload)? I assume it's because it would be slow to have to constantly serialize/deserialize every back and forth?

How does the [STOMP](https://stomp.github.io/) protocol address this? I get that it moves the binary-to-text conversion to the server, but at the expense of the "messages" being larger so is it really that much faster than a JS client that can serialize/deserialize AMQP?

Comment: "Why doesn't" questions are often unanswerable. It doesn't because it doesn't. Perhaps there's a technical hurdle that makes it impossible, but then if it was designed differently it could have been accommodated. Perhaps the reason is just that that's not what the developers were focusing on. Why doesn't it run on Atari? Well... because nobody has made it work on Atari yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this question is tends to be primarily opinion-based, have a look at section *1.2.4 The Advanced Message Queuing Protocol (AMQP)* in [AMQP Protocol Specification](https://www.rabbitmq.com/resources/specs/amqp0-9-1.pdf):

> The design of AMQ model was driven by these requirements:
>
> - To guarantee interoperability between conforming implementations.
> - To provide explicit control over the quality of service.
> - To be consistent and explicit in naming.
> - To allow complete configuration of server wiring via the protocol.
> - To use a command notation that maps easily into application-level API's.
> - To be clear, so each operation does exactly one thing.
>
> The design of AMQP transport layer was driven by these main
> requirements, in no particular order:
>
> - To be compact, using a binary encoding that packs and unpacks rapidly.
> - To handle messages of any size without significant limit.
> - To carry multiple channels across a single connection.
> - To be long-lived, with no significant in-built limitations.
> - To allow asynchronous command pipe-lining.
> - To be easily extended to handle new and changed needs.
> - To be forward compatible with future versions.
> - To be repairable, using a strong assertion model.
> - To be neutral with respect to programming languages.
> - To fit a code generation process.

For better understanding (e.g. why one decisions was preferred over another) reading through whole specification is highly recommended.